# Setting value of h:inputtext field using jquery script

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsf

I'm designing a page that is supposed to allow users to submit possible computing science projects and at one stage the user will have to enter a duration that the project will run over. To make things easier on the user the I'm trying to fill out the from: to: fields using jQuery's datepicker method however I cannot get the script to run when the user selects the appropriate field.

So far I've got the following script:

```
<h:outputScript library="jquery" name="jquery-1.9.1.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="jquery" name="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.js"/>
<h:outputScript library="jquery" name="jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js"/>

<h:head>
    <title>Add project</title>

    <script type="text/javascript" id="setDate">
        $(function() {
            $(" #datepicker ").datepicker();
        });
    </script>
    <!-- rest omitted for readability -->
```

and my h:inputText looks like this:

```
<h:inputText id="setDate" value="" onclick="$('#datepicker').datepicker();"/>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

I did try to make it work without using any jsf tags and managed to get it up and running but I just can seem to make it work with jsf tags.

The problem is that when in a browser the jQuery datepicker widget does not display upon clicking on the field. Clicking on the field defined using the standard `<input>` tag works correctly.

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: sorry, probably a bit unclear. Issue is that when selecting the input field in the browser the datepicker widget does not display. This is not an issue when using the normal <input> tag. Only when using JSF

Comment: Why do you have two tags with the id = "setDate"?

Comment: @DannyThunder, sorry leftover from a bit of trial and error.

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 $( document ).ready(function() {
   function openDatePicker(){
      $("#datepicker").datepicker();
   }
 });
</script>

<h:inputText id="setDate" value="" onclick="openDatePicker();"/>
<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" /></p>
```

Hope this will work for you (havent tried it out).

Comment: I managed to get it working by tweaking your answer slightly, thank you very much for putting me on the right track.

Comment: What did you do @MWold ? Post me the edit and check my answer as right as soon as I edit it? :-)

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve my problem in the following way:

Changed my script to:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".datepicker").datepicker({

        });
    });
</script>
```

and my jsf tag to:

```
<h:inputText styleClass="datepicker"/>
```

Now the datepicker widget will display when I select the field. Thanks to DannyThunder for putting me on the right track.

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer for me:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
     $('#signup-form\\:email').checkEmailFormat();      
   });
</script>
```

And for Primefaces:

```
<script>
   jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('signup-form:emil')).checkEmailFormat();
   });
</script>
```

I got the information from [mkyong.com](https://www.mkyong.com/jsf2/primefaces/how-to-get-jsf-id-via-jquery/)

Best regards